# Extend Endpoint to show Created By User ID

Tags: acumatica

I need to be able to see the Created By and/or the Last Updated By User ID's for a Document or Transaction (example Inventory Receipt).   How can I add these fields to my extended Web Services Endpoint as these fields are not showing up in the list of DAC fields for this entity?  Note that I have the same issue on other entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field doesn’t show up on the list because it doesn’t have a PXUIFieldAttribute / is not visible on the page, but you can still type the underlying field name directly when adding it to the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel, so do I just use the DB column name?

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel, that worked.  I used LastModifiedByID and CreatedByID and the endpoint was validated.

Comment: @DianeCawley glad to hear it works. It needs to be the DAC field name, which usually matches an underlying DB column 1:1